# WPF: Add a Border inside an element

Tags: c#, wpf, image, border

I'd like to know if there is a way to add a Border *inside* an image. I want something like the "Stroke" effect in Photoshop when the position is set to inside, i.e. it has to be painted over the image. Is it possible?

Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could place the border on top of the image :

```
<Grid>
 <Image/>
 <Border/>
</Grid>
```

---

If you have set a `CornerRadius`, and you want to hide the `Image` in the corners, that's more complicated, but you could set another almost same `Border` as the `OpacityMask` to your `Image` :

```
<Grid>
    <!-- I used Rectangle instead of Image for the example -->
    <Rectangle Width="50" Height="50" Fill="Red">
        <Rectangle.OpacityMask>
            <VisualBrush>
                <VisualBrush.Visual>
                    <Border Width="50" Height="50" Background="Black" 
                            CornerRadius="10"/>
                </VisualBrush.Visual>
            </VisualBrush>
        </Rectangle.OpacityMask>
    </Rectangle>
</Grid>
```

Comment: It works but if I set a corner radius the "pointed" corners of the Image are visible beyond the Border...

Answer (score 3):

That's easy i think

```
<Grid>
    <Image />
    <Border/>
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes you could do a multilayer approach!

```
<Grid>
    <Image />
    <Border horizontalAlignment="Stretch" verticalAlignment="Stretch" />
</Grid>
```

Remind the attributes you need to use, this is just a lightweight version!